# How to remove extra space between 2 paragraph.... in flutter html

Tags: flutter

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: paragraphs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final paragraphContent = paragraphs[index].trim();

            // Check if the paragraph content contains HTML tags
            final isHtmlContent = paragraphs[index].contains('<');

            if (isHtmlContent) {
              final processedHtmlContent =
                  processHtmlContent(paragraphContent);
              return Html(data: processedHtmlContent);
            } else {
              
              // Render the plain text content
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child:
                    Text(paragraphContent, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

Example output
In common usage and statistics, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally

Establishment

In common usage and statistics, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally

my data is showing like that... please help me in this... How i remove this extra space from my data and can show on the screen ??

I am expecting this answer..

In common usage and statistics, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally

Establishment
In common usage and statistics, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally

Comment: maybe you can try with `.replace`

Comment: can you please update you code to provide a snippet of your paragraph content related to this post?